# Pandas and Plotly: Understanding code differences that lead to errors or functional output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, data-science, data-analysis

I've tried to ask gpt, but anyyhing that he said is just some problems wtih type and check your data. I'm just trying to understand the difference between first and second ways. As I understand It used to work same.

Why when I'm trying to do

```
data1.loc[:, "ЗП(руб)"] = data1["ЗП(руб)"].fillna(0).astype(float)

fig = px.histogram(
    data_frame= np.log(data1["ЗП(руб)"]+1),
    x = 'ЗП(руб)',
    nbins=30,
    title='Распределние зарплаты соискателей в рублях с использованием логарифмического графика'
)
fig.show()
```

Python write:

`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log' ...  ---> 41     data_frame= np.log(data1['ЗП(руб)']+1), ... TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable log method`

BUT when I change It starting work.

`data1.loc[:, 'ЗП(руб)'] = data1['ЗП(руб)'].fillna(0).astype(float)`

`data1['ЗП(руб)'] = data1['ЗП(руб)'].fillna(0).astype(float)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.